# mongodb has unexpectedly crashed

Tags: mongodb

mongodb has unexpectedly crashed with following stack:

```
Sun Dec 29 11:30:43 [conn410] build index XXX { referral: 1 }
Sun Dec 29 11:30:43 [conn410] build index done 26597 records 0.056 secs
Sun Dec 29 11:30:43 Invalid access at address: 0

Sun Dec 29 11:30:43 Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).

Sun Dec 29 11:30:43 Backtrace:
0xa83fc9 0xa845a0 0x7fdad2200490 0x54d7dc 0x83d551 0x83d756 0x83d8b0 0x9493e3 0x8c0b66       0x8cd4b0 0x8cdb06 0x8d21ce 0x8d3be5 0x8d40e0 0x8d6200 0x94360d 0x948375 0x8823bc 0x885405 0xa96a46 
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x399) [0xa83fc9]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo24abruptQuitWithAddrSignalEiP7siginfoPv+0x220) [0xa845a0]
 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf490) [0x7fdad2200490]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo24FieldRangeVectorIterator7advanceERKNS_7BSONObjE+0x4c) [0x54d7dc]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11BtreeCursor29skipOutOfRangeKeysAndCheckEndEv+0x81) [0x83d551]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11BtreeCursor12skipAndCheckEv+0x26) [0x83d756]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11BtreeCursor7advanceEv+0x100) [0x83d8b0]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8UpdateOp4nextEv+0x253) [0x9493e3]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12QueryPlanSet6Runner6nextOpERNS_7QueryOpE+0x56) [0x8c0b66]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12QueryPlanSet6Runner4nextEv+0x110) [0x8cd4b0]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12QueryPlanSet6Runner22runUntilFirstCompletesEv+0x56) [0x8cdb06]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12QueryPlanSet5runOpERNS_7QueryOpE+0x11e) [0x8d21ce]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16MultiPlanScanner9runOpOnceERNS_7QueryOpE+0x525) [0x8d3be5]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11MultiCursor10nextClauseEv+0x70) [0x8d40e0]
           /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11MultiCursorC1EPKcRKNS_7BSONObjES5_N5boost10shared_ptrINS0_8CursorOpEEEb+0x220) [0x8d6200]
   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14_updateObjectsEbPKcRKNS_7BSONObjES2_bbbRNS_7OpDebugEPNS_11RemoveSaverE+0x35d) [0x94360d]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13updateObjectsEPKcRKNS_7BSONObjES2_bbbRNS_7OpDebugE+0x125) [0x948375]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14receivedUpdateERNS_7MessageERNS_5CurOpE+0x47c) [0x8823bc]
   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0x1105) [0x885405]
  /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0x76) [0xa96a46]

Logstream::get called in uninitialized state
Sun Dec 29 11:30:43 ERROR: Client::~Client _context should be null but is not; client:conn
Logstream::get called in uninitialized state
Sun Dec 29 11:30:43 ERROR: Client::shutdown not called: conn
```

how can I know what caused the crashing? Is there another log that describes more details?

Comment: Maybe should you try asking on sefverfault.com or superuser.com?

Comment: Is this somehow related to java? IT seems to me that it is just mongodb problem...

Comment: It seems like a problem when forming the cursor serverside, either way you might wanna post this on mongodb-user google group, also state your mongodb vesion

Comment: how about letting us know what platform this was on and what version of mongod you are running?  also what other operations were going on at the same time other than index build?

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution to this error? Would be nice to have the solution shared below.